# Converting user input from integer to double

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to ask the user to enter 4 integer values followed by 4 double values. I keep getting the error "possible lossy conversion from double to int". I have tried different things but don't understand the simple conversion. Also.. might there be a better approach to this? Any advice for me is helpful. Eventually I am going to print out the values of these down the road...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       int[] intNumbers = new int[4];

       // Prompt user to enter 4 integer values here
       System.out.println("Enter 4 integer numbers below");

       // intNumbers only excepts 4 values with the for loop
       for (int i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextInt(); i++) {
           intNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
       }

       double[] dblNumbers = new double[4];

       // Prompt users to enter 4 double values here
       System.out.println("Enter 4 double numbers below");

       // dblNumbers only excepts 4 values with the for loop
       for (double i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
           dblNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using a `double` as an index into your array.  Always use an `int` as an index.  Change

```
for (double i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
    dblNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

to

```
//   vvv
for (int i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
    dblNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: So how should I go about this then because I need to prompt the user to input 4 integers and 4 doubles. Maybe an array is not the best idea?

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart do not confuse the indices and the values in the array. What do you think `dblNumbers[i]` means?

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart Your approach was generally correct, but the index of the array is always an `int`, regardless of the type you need to store in the array.  Note how the `double` is still be read from the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Double in your for-loop, which is not a good idea. Array indexes are always in int, so if you assign a double to it, it will give "possible loss conversion from double to int".

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextDouble(); i++) {         
    dblNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
```